# create JSON with multiple dictionaries, Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this code:

```
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> keys = dict([(x, x**3) for x in xrange(1, 3)])
>>> nums = json.dumps(keys, indent=4)
>>> print nums
{
    "1": 1,
    "2": 8
}
```

But I want to create a loop to make my output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 8
    },
    {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 8
    },
    {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 8
    }
]
```

Comment: Does not make sense. What you want is not a valid JSON document.

Comment: How to create a loop for a valid JSON document?

Comment: @Serg: I've edited the output to make it valid JSON, provided you meant it to be a list.

Comment: just change to `keys = [dict([(x, x**3) for x in xrange(1, 3)])]*3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to create a list, append all the mappings to that *before* conversion to JSON:

```
output = []
for something in somethingelse:
    output.append(dict([(x, x**3) for x in xrange(1, 3)])
json.dumps(output)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your desired output is not valid JSON. I think what you probably meant to do was to append multiple dictionaries to a list, like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> multikeys = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...    multikeys.append(dict([(x, x**3) for x in xrange(1, 3)]))
... 
>>> print json.dumps(multikeys, indent=4)
[
    {
        "1": 1, 
        "2": 8
    }, 
    {
        "1": 1, 
        "2": 8
    }, 
    {
        "1": 1, 
        "2": 8
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sign_up():
    global list
    user_name = input("Enter your User_Name: ")
    password = input("Enter your Password: ")
    user_ID = random.choice(ID)
    dict ={"user_name":user_name,"password":password,"user_ID":user_ID}
    with open("sign_up_details.json", "r") as file:
        read_data = file.read()
        load_data = json.loads(read_data)
        load_data.append(dict)
        new_data = json.dumps(load_data, indent=4)
    with open("", "w") as file:
        file.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).